# A/B Testing extension for Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5, ab-testing

We are seeking to start doing A/B testing on our Joomla websites.
We are looking for either:

- a Joomla extension (commerical is ok)
- a third party service with a Joomla plugin.
- a recommended strategy for workaround

Additional Notes:

Yes, I checked the Joomla extention's directory and found one option with no reviews or updates for over a year -- not a huge confidence builder.

Yes, I read this question: http://goo.gl/qZhU4 which is asking a different question and resulted in different results.

We are running Joomla 2.5 and need a solution that will keep up with latest version(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Website Optimizer has a Joomla plugin. You can see it at http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/split-testing-blog/ab-testing-joomla-plugin/

-Siddharth
(I work for VWO)

Answer (score 2):

We've only tried a couple, the one on the [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/miscellaneous/development/12729) and [this one](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/split-testing-blog/ab-testing-joomla-plugin/).  I wasn't directly involved with the project, so can't tell you much else, but I'm sure they're adaptable if they aren't exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

My company Polished Geek recently released two new Joomla! 2.5 plugins for A/B testing. They work with Convert.com Experiments toolset (http://www.convert.com/). There is both a general Joomla plugin and a VirtueMart 2 eCommerce specialized plugin that captures order and product information.

Joomla Extension Directory Links (which also have links to documentation) -

**J!Convert: Convert Experiments for Joomla!** - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/site-analytics-cloud-based/22493

**Convert Experiments for VirtueMart** - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-stats/22414

I hope you find these useful!

Answer (score 1):

Just researching an answer for this question too and found a newer extension, "DM A/B Test" since these answers have been posted:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/planned-content/dm-a-b-test

From €39.90, Joomla 2.5 and 3.x compatible and can be installed on multiple domains.

Comment: Only one review though, let us know if you use it